# Lagrange inversion for power-series with rational powers

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, power-series

One can use Lagrange inversion to find the
power series $F(x)$, which solves $F(x) = x(1+F(x)^p)$,
where $p$ is a positive integer.

Now, what if $p$ is not an integer, but rather a positive rational number,
say $p=7/3$?

As a concrete example, we are looking for a formal solution to $F(x) = x(1+F(x)^{7/3})$,
but now, $F(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x^{1/3}]$.

The Lagrange inversion formula still seem to work in this case,
that is, the function
$$
F(x) := \sum_{r>0} x^r \left( [t^{r-1}]\frac{1}{r} (1+t^p)^r \right)
$$
is a solution to $F(x) = x(1+F(x)^p)$, but now we must have $F(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x^{1/d}]$,
where $d$ is the denominator of $p$, and the sum ranges over all positive integer multiples of $1/d$.

Is there some reference which proves this extension of Lagrange inversion?

Edit: I think I managed to prove that Lagrange inversion generalizes to this setting, i.e,
instead of having $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x]$,
we have $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x^{1/d}]$,
and we wish to express the coefficients of $g$,
in terms of the coefficients of $f$, where $f(g(x))=x$.

Comment: but for $r=1$ we get $[x]F=1$, so $F=x+\ldots$ and $F^p$ is not a power series?

Comment: @FedorPetrov right, we need to allow for fractional powers also. I think actually I can manage to prove the above, so I am typing it up... the proof given in https://users.math.msu.edu/users/magyarp/math880/Lagrange.pdf should generalize to the setting i am interested in..

Comment: But $F/x$ is a power series while $1+F^p$ is not, how can they be equal?

Comment: Well, $F(x)$ is not a power series, but rather a power-series in the variable $x^{1/d}$.

Comment: ah, $r$ does not run over integers?

Comment: @FedorPetrov exactly, it must run over some subset of the rational numbers (or all rational numbers, should be valid for this also)

Comment: On the formal side (with any complex exponent $p$), if we put $y:=x^p$ and $f(y):=F(x)^p$, the equation becomes
$f(y)=y(1+f(y))^p$, so $f$ is the inverse of $g(z):=z(1+z)^{-p}$, for which the standard Lagrange inversion applies.

Comment: Right, so one can find an equation for the pth power, but then one is left with taking a pth root of a formal power series, which is not easy in general.

Comment: But in this case we can easily write all complex powers of $f(y)/y$  as mentioned in my answer below; in particular to the exponent $1/p$. I think this gives the existence and uniqueness for your $F$: of course, specifying in which class of formal series the solution $F$ has to be. I'll wirte it down.

Comment: There is no problem in taking the $p$th root of a formal power series. If $G(x)$ is any formal power series we can write $G(x) = ax^b H(x)$ where $H(x)$ is a formal power series with constant term 1. Then $G(x)^{1/p}=a^{1/p} x^{b/p} H(x)^{1/p}$.

Comment: @IraGessel I was thinking that finding the actual coefficients (closed formulas) of the pth root is not straightforward, given closed formals of the series itself.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson But in applying Lagrange inversion there is usually no problem in finding these powers; Lagrange inversion gives a formula for the coefficients of arbitrary powers of the power series to be solved for.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson In cases like this it's often useful to apply Lagrange inversion to an equation like $f = R(f)$ rather than $f=xR(f)$. Thus if we want to solve $F =x (1+F^p)$ we can set $F(x) = xG(x^p)$ and $y=x^p$; then $F=x(1+F^p)$ reduces to $G(y) = 1+ yG(y)^p$, the well-known Fuss-Catalan functional equation.

Answer (score 9):

Let $p$ be any non-zero complex exponent. Let $f \in x\big(1+\mathbb C[[x]]\big)\subset \mathbb C[[x]]$ be the well-known compositional inverse of  $x(1+x)^{-p}\in x\big(1+\mathbb C[[x]]\big)$ given by the Lagrange inversion:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n {pn\choose n-1}x^n,$$

and consider its formal conjugate $F(x):=f(x^p)^{1/p}$, thus  an element of $M:=x\big(1+\mathbb C[[x^p]]\big)$. Since  $f$ solves  $f(x)=x\big(1+f(x)\big)^p$ we have that $F$ solves in $M$  $$F(x)=x\big(1+F(x)^p\big).$$
This on the formal side; also, e.g. for small real nonnegative $x$, one gets a convergent series.

*(Not needed here).* There is also an easy extension of the Lagrange inversion formula that already works in $X^\alpha\mathbb C((X))$ as a $\mathbb C((X))$-module, for $\alpha\in\mathbb C$.  I reported it in the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#The_Lagrange_inversion_formula). An application is e.g. the power series expansion of the [complex powers of the Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Integer_and_complex_powers).

Comment: Ah, that's nice.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to write up a proof based on [these lecture notes](https://users.math.msu.edu/users/magyarp/math880/Lagrange.pdf) (which cites Stanley's EC2)

The original proof uses residue calculus, and properties of analytic functions. This proof does not generalize to rational exponents, but the proof linked above, extends without any issues to "power series" with rational powers.